# Parentheses under equations with two lines of text Rmarkdown

Tags: text, r-markdown, equations

I would like to write in a Rmarkdown document an equation with some explanations below it. I have found the functions `\underbrace{}` coupled with `_\textrm{}`.

```
\underbrace{X}_\textrm{Text1 for X} = \underbrace{Y}_\textrm{Text1 for Y}
```

This is working perfectly fine for me. What I would like to add is a second text line for the variable X and Y. I tried splitting the text inside `\textrm{}` and adding a new term `\textrm{}`. But none of those solutions worked. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [tex.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7504/56508), you can use `\substack` (and `\\` for newlines):

```
$$\underbrace{X}_{\substack{\textrm{Text1 for X}\\  \textrm{Text2 for X}}}$$
```